# Which delayed luggage compensation is mandatory in the EU?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airlines, delays, compensation

I was flying from Germany to Turkey with AtlasGlobal, with a transfer in Serbia. My luggage unfortunately stayed in Serbia. Because of late departure they had short time to transfer the luggage. I complained and filed a report. The luggage arrived the next day, in total **34.5 hours delay**.

I sent a complaint email and asked for compensation. They told me that they give up to 50$ a day for our purchases for clothes etc. I bought after my landing some shirts and underwear. They said if I provide the bills for the clothes they can reimburse this amount back to me. I provided the bills and then they said they will not reimburse any money because the luggage arrived to me in 24 hours. This is not true and they didn't mention this in the first e-mail and I feel very annoyed. Is there any place I can complain them?

Answer (score 5):

There isn't an EU regulation which obligates the airline to offer you any sort of compensation for delayed luggage. Therefore the most you can do is contact customer support showing that your luggage was indeed delayed by more than 24 hours.

Comment: Because it was a international flight, the Montreal Convention on delayed baggage applies. Unfortunately, that entitles you to compensation only after 21 days.